# How to catch svg image fail to load in D3?

Tags: image, d3.js, load

I am using D3 to create a visualization with rows of `<image>` svg elements.

Could anyone know how I can upload a replacement image if the image file is not available?

```
    var images= imageGroup.append('svg:image')
           .attr("xlink:href",function(d,i){
                       //lines of code to process filename
                 return "/img/" + filename + ".jpg"

           })
```

Answer (score 5):

I know it's an old post but i found a simpler solution than *Mark* answer. So i post it for future users with the same issue.

In *d3.js* you can add events listeners on nodes (`click`, `load`, `error`, ...). So when the image fails to load you can change the link (with `setAttribute()` function) to a fallback image. Here is a working example (note that you should not add `xlink:` before `href` ):

```
var images = imageGroup.append('svg:image')
    .attr("href", function(d){
        return "ThisImageWillFailsToLoad.jpg"
    })
    .on("error", function(d){
        this.setAttribute("href", "YourFallbackImage.jpg");
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

This is more a JavaScript question then `d3.js`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <svg width="100" height="100"></svg>
  <script>
    
    // set up svg image tag
    var images = d3.select("svg")
      .append('svg:image')
      .attr('width', 50)
      .attr('height', 50);

    // create a test image
    var imgTest = new Image();
    // if it loads successfully add it to the svg image
    imgTest.onload = function() {
      images.attr("xlink:href", imgTest.src);
    }
    // if it fails test another image
    imgTest.onerror = function() {
      imgTest.src = "https://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff.png&text=An+Image!"
    }
    // this will fail
    imgTest.src = "https://does.not/exist.png";

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var images= imageGroup.append('svg:image')
  .attr("xlink:href",function(d,i){
    return "/img/" + filename + ".jpg"
  })
  // execute the callback function if the image fails to load
  .on('error', function(d) {
    // specify a default path for the image
    d3.select(this).attr("xlink:href", "/defaultPath");
  });
```

Comment: @altocumulus I have added an explanation to the code. There may be some places that are not explained clearly. If you don't understand it, you can ask me and I will improve the explanation. I have practiced it in my own project and it is feasible.