# Ignore missing images in SVG with D3 data and enter methods

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

**EDIT**: I found a solution for this exact issue (which the "duplicate" issue linked does not solve). I will post at the bottom of this question, as I can no longer add an answer, only edit.

When using D3, I am adding images to an SVG from a dynamic data source. Something like this:

```
var images = [
  'https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/339630?v=3&s=460',
]

d3.select('svg')
  .data(images)
  .append('image')
  .attr('xlink:href', function(d) { return d; })
  .attr('width', 200)
  .attr('height', 200)
```

When an image does not exist, it displays a broken image like so:

[image: missing image image]

How can I make nothing render at all? I know I can do something like this:

```
const img = $('<img>')
img.on('load', () => {
    // image exists! use it...
})
img.on('error', () => {
    // image does not exist. do nothing...
})
img.attr({ src: 'the url' })
```

But I do not understand how to use this technique with D3 `data` and `enter`.

## Solution:

```
        node.append('image')
            .attr('id', (d, i) => 'image-' + i)

        data.forEach((d, i) => {
            const src = d.src
            var imgTest = new Image()
            imgTest.onload = function() {
                svg.select('#image-' + i).attr('xlink:href', src)
            }
            imgTest.onerror = function() {
                // imgTest.src = "fallback image url"
            }
            imgTest.src = src
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find a solution to your problem here. Not the prettiest but still working

[How to catch svg image fail to load in D3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39988146/how-to-catch-svg-image-fail-to-load-in-d3)

Spoiler alert, you might need to pre-load images to detect the failure or not, something that doesn't exist in svg

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that's what I'm going to have to do, however the part I'm confused about is HOW to do that when I am using D3 `enter`. i.e. for multiple images. Some might fail, and others won't. In your linked answer, there is only the one image. (although I admittedly only put one image in the array in my example)

Comment: Thanks again. I adapted the linked answer to apply to this scenario.

Comment: awesome ! have a great one.